# Is it possible to send a file from the client computer on a perl web application without uploading it to the server first?

Tags: perl, file-upload, www-mechanize

I've looked for this around the internet without getting any good answer so far, so here's the issue:

I have a perl web application used by a small group of people (accessed by their web browser on windows computers, around 100 users) , on an intranet (this application is on a RedHat Apache server) , this application gets the user's inputs and uses `WWW::Mechanize` to send everything to another page on (a different server, which shouldn't be used directly), process a form and return the result (I know it may not sound optimal, but it was done according to what was required), the issue here is that I need the users to be able to send a file (most likely it will be an image of ~500kB, either through `WWW::Mechanize` along with the other form data that gets submitted, or by an email with an attachment, either option is equally acceptable), and I know the file can be sent/attached if it's already on the server, my question is simple:

**Is it possible to send a file from the client computer (running the perl web application on the browser) without uploading it to the server (that will send it) first?**

**P.S.** This is not one of those "give me the code" questions, I'm not asking for any specific code, I just want to know if this is something that could be done (and if it is to have an idea how), or if I absolutely have to upload the file to the server running the perl application first (I already have a script for that). If this is not possible it's ok, I just want to be sure if I need to upload to the server first before sending the file.

Comment: I'm not sure that the issue at hand is very clear. could you try to elaborate?

Comment: Basically, I want to use either `WWW::Mechanize` (to another page with a form to upload it) or a module like `MIME::Lite` (as an attachment) to send a file, from a web application running on perl, however I want to know if the file could be sent straight from the client or if it HAS to be loaded to the server and sent from there

Comment: @darkajax sent where, from what client, or loaded to what server, and sent how, when, why?

Comment: (Everything is on an intranet) Windows Client computers 1 to 100 use (with their web browser) a perl web application running on linux Server1, this app uses `WWW::Mechanize` to send some data to Server2, and I need to either upload a file along with that data, or send an email to a specific address with an attachment (either one is fine)

Comment: If Server1 can effectively POST a file on Server2 using WWW::Mechanize, you should be able to do it directly from the Windows browser as well, assuming a proper form can be served from Server2 and there aren't any other access restrictions preventing your from speaking directly with Server2. Of course, if Server1 also does something more that needs to be done before everything can be sent to Server2, I do not see how you could skip sending it to Server1 first. Theoretically, you could send things from the browser two different places, using ajax and cross origin requests (challenging)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand you correctly, yes, you can upload a file through [WWW::Mechanize](https://www.metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize). See the `pb-upload` example.

Comment: Good example, actually I had seen it before, in that case the .jpg files are on the server itself (I know that can be done, but I want to know if there's any way to do that with files on the client computer)

Comment: Yes, but in your case you indicate that the client is using WWW::Mechanize. WWW::Mechanize is a client-side library, prentending to be a browser, so posting a file like that example does should work fine since your app and file then will be on the client, posting to a server, getting results back.

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing where the perl application using WWW::Mechanize is actually running? Even though perl is often used server-side, it can be used client-side as well, which is what I'm guessing based on what you've written.

Comment: Sorry I should've posted the question differently, `WWW::Mechanize` is used by the perl web application (running on the linux server) by the Web browser on the Windows Client computer.

Comment: So is there a third server involved, i.e. you want to send it from the web client to a _third_ server (not the linux web application)? If not, you are effectively asking how to upload a file to the server...

Comment: Well there's just 2 servers and 1 client, 1 where the perl app that uses `WWW:Mechanize` is, and 1 where the data coming from the Client goes by the first server using `WWW:Mechanize`, there's a form there and the data is submitted, an optional part of that form has a field to submit a file, and using `WWW:Mechanize` I know I could submit a file existing on the first server, but what I wanted to know was if I could do the same with a file on the Client computer.

Comment: Another option I have is to send an email from the first server with the file attached, OVERALL, what I wanted to know is if all of this could be done WITHOUT uploading the file to the first server (I know how to do that, so that's not at all what I'm asking) :)

Comment: Do you have to upload it from the browser? Do Server1 need everything except the file? How would you associate information sent to Server1 with the file sent to Server2? Which interfaces for receiving files does Server2 support? Is it a requirement to send the file from the browser directly? Regardless, what you are asking seems very specific to your servers, applications and use cases, so unless you can simplify it a bit, I doubt there will be very much specific help to get from here.

Comment: Ok, got it, I'll review the whole process and keep in mind your advice. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done **if** the client computer has a mail client that is configurable enough to allow a commmand of the type "mail $TO $SUBJECT -attachment $ATT_FILE". Even then you need user to cooperate by launching the action.

Otherwise, no. You can't do it via JavaScript AFAIK due to sandbox restrictions.

I don't know enough about Flash to know if that's an option.